# url gets changed in SharePoint hyperlink column

Tags: sharepoint, alternate-access-mappings

I have a SharePoint 2010 web application "myapp.test.com" and I have extended this application to myapp-edit.test.com

I also have configured the following two alternative access mapping urls:

```
•myapp.test.com (Zone: Default) 
•myapp-edit.test.com (Zone: Intranet)
```

I have created a list with an hyperlink column. The problem is that when I add an item to this list with url: `myapp.test.com/Pages/myPage.aspx` then this url gets changed to

```
myapp-edit.test.com/Pages/myPage.aspx
```

How do I make it stay as `myapp.test.com/Pages/myPage.aspx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to make it `/Pages/myPage.aspx`, and it will work in both cases.

Comment: When I put myapp-edit.test.com/Pages/myPage.aspx this will change to /Pages/myPage.aspx (in page source). But when I editing this item, the url displays as myapp-edit.test.com/Pages/myPage.aspx . 

Now I know this is depends on URL address. When I visit the server using: myapp.test.com, all urls will have myapp.test.com as a prefix. The same thing applies to myapp-edit.test.com

Thanks!